# Querying builds from TFS with QueryBuilds has very low performance

Tags: c#, tfs, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to reach each build in my local TFS 2015 server which has the "Retain Indefinitely" flag (`BuildDetail.KeepForever` Property) yet the `QueryBuilds()` function takes too long to get all of the builds.

[TFS 2015 'Retain Indefinitely' Web GUI Menu Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAgR5.png)

All I actually need is the `KeepForever` and the `DropLocation` properties.

I Found out you can get better efficiency using the `IBuildDetailSpec` interface yet I couldn't find an option in which I'll get the `KeepForever` property.

My current code snippet:

```cs
public void BackupOnlyRetainedBuilds(string TeamProjectName, string DestinationPath)
{
    defs[...]

    Uri configurationServerUri = new Uri("http://builder:8080/tfs");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(configurationServerUri);

    //get builds server
    buildServer = (IBuildServer)server.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

    //set up an array of all build definition from a spcific team project.
    IBuildDefinition[] bda = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(TeamProjectName);

    //check each build definition.
    foreach (var buildDefinition in bda)
    {
        //set an array of builds history.
        IBuildDetail[] bha = buildDefinition.QueryBuilds();

        //check each build from build history build details.
        foreach (var buildDetails in bha)
        {
            //check if build is retained.
            if (buildDetails.KeepForever == true)
            {
                string dropLocationPath = buildDetails.DropLocation;

                //check if drop folder exists.
                if (Directory.Exists(dropLocationPath))
                {
                    //create all of the directories.
                    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(dropLocationPath, "*",
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(dropLocationPath, DestinationPath));

                    //copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name.
                    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(dropLocationPath, "*.*",
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(dropLocationPath, DestinationPath), true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `QueryBuilds` to not grab all the build details, but only the ones you're interested in, from my patched version of `tfsbuild.exe`:

```
buildDetailSpec = this.BuildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(...)
buildDetailSpec.QueryDeletedOption = !forDestroy ? QueryDeletedOption.IncludeDeleted : QueryDeletedOption.OnlyDeleted;
buildDetailSpec.InformationTypes = null;
IBuildQueryResult buildQueryResult = this.BuildServer.QueryBuilds(buildDetailSpec);
```

Or alternatively use `QueryBuildsUri` and pass it `(string[]) null, QueryOptions.None`:

```
IBuildDetail[] buildDetailArray = this.BuildServer.QueryBuildsByUri(list2.ToArray(), (string[]) null, QueryOptions.None, QueryDeletedOption.IncludeDeleted);
```

You may need to pass it a specific set of `InformationTypes` depending on the data you need as part of your backup tool.

Comment: Thank you! `buildDetailSpec.InformationTypes = null;` & `IBuildQueryResult` did the trick but I couldn't find documentation to show me what is the difference between the different InformationTypes and why null making it much faster than normal.

Comment: Each record and attachment in the build time line is an BuildInfo record. Each record has a type. When you query builds, by default all records are deserialized when you retrieve or query a build. This can be many MB of data to deserialize and put into memory, I've seen builds with 50+ MB of data in these records. By passing an empty array or null you tell the system to only return the root records. Which is a couple of KB at most. Hence the enormous speedup.

Comment: Test results and coverage and every line output by any tool included in the build, they all end up as a I BuildInfo record.

Comment: Here is a list of all the types of information that can be stored on a build: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/cc339624%28v%3dvs.110%29?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&